# How to rewrite requests to index.php to parent directory

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, symfony, mod-rewrite

I have a website with two .htaccess files one in the projects root directory and one in the /Project Root/Public/ directory and I want to rewrite direct requests to "http://localhost/Project Root/index.php" to "http://localhost/Project Root/" how would I go about doing this?

My current .htaccess(s):

Project Root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

/Project Root/Public/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(?:/+(.+/))?public/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301,NE]

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$0 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BASE:%1]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .+
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%0]

    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} =""
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your `Project Root .htaccess` like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^/]+/)?index\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteRule .* public/$0 [L]
```

Make sure you clear your browser cache before testing.